# XPath - How to select by @text that contains new line

Tags: mobile, xpath

In the Mobile application view I see text like this:

*Test string*

*with new line*

But in the elements tree of this view (it looks like expandible tree viewer) I see value of the @text attribute of this one like this:

*Test stringwith new line*

I have tried to use the following ways:

```
xpath=//*[@text='Test string\nwith new line']

xpath=//*[@text=concat('Test string','\n','with new line']
```

But they don't work.

Is it possible to select element by its @text attribute containing new line?
If it is possible How to do that?

**Note:** I don't have ability to see source code and change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a good way to place a single newline character into an XPath, but you could use `normalize-space()` if your main objective is to select the element and the fact that it contains a newline isn't all that important:

```
//*[normalize-space(@text) = 'Test string with new line']
```

Comment: Thanks @jlrishe, it helped. But example is little bit incorrect. I have changed it to : `//*[normalize-space(@text)='Test string with new line']` and now it works.